# Android Start Activity from Class

Tags: android, xamarin.android

```
public class WeeklyInspection : Activity
{
  WebView view = (WebView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.inspectionWV);
  view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
  view.Settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.CacheElseNetwork;
  view.SetWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient(this));
  view.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(this));
  view.LoadUrl("http://myurl.com");
}

private class CustomWebChromeClient: WebChromeClient
{
   public override void OnConsoleMessage(string message, int lineNumber, string sourceID)
    {
       if (message.StartsWith("Submit")
          //do all my submit stuff here
          //if without error, I want to go back to the Main Activity.  Have tried:
          Intent intent = new Intent(BaseContext, typeof(Main));
          StartActivity(intent); //Both BaseContext and StartActivity throw "Cannot access non-static method in static context"
          //tried:
          Finish(); //Same thing
          //tried:
          OnBackPressed(); //Same thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your question if you want any help...

Comment: It is in the CustomWebChromeClient.  Please read my comments.

Comment: The question is in his //comments if you read them.
Try formatting your Intent/StartActivity like this: Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler error message you encountered states, [StartActivity](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.Content.Context.StartActivity%28Type%29) is an instance method of [Context](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Content.Context), not a static method, and therefore cannot be called like that.

You didn't include it in the code sample, but in the activity you pass "this" (the activity) into the constructor to CustomWebChromeClient, so I'm assuming CustomWebChromeClient is keeping a reference to it. You can use that reference to call the instance methods you need on the activity, whether it be StartActivity, Finish, or whatever else you need. For example:

```
private class CustomWebChromeClient: WebChromeClient
{
    private readonly Activity _context;

    public CustomWebChromeClient(Activity context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override void OnConsoleMessage(string message, int lineNumber, string sourceID)
    {
        if (message.StartsWith("Submit"))
        {
            _context.Finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Just Use This**

```
Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```